# Database entry for every webpage view (analytics)

Tags: java, sql, playframework

I am playing around (learning experience) with writing an analytic system using the Play! Framework(2)(java),

I want to write efficient code and due to this I am struggling to decide on the following:

For every view a page gets there is a record being added, specifying the website (example.org) , page (/index.html) and the date that was viewed. As you can guess, the amount of rows is going to be huge.
To use the data I am then selecting all rows where the website is "example.org", looping through the results to build a hash map containing the date and how many views it had on that date and then using this to build a graph.

There must be a more better way of doing this,

For example, rather than having a row per view would it be better to update an existing record adding one view to the record.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add some more conditions (like the date) in your WHERE clause, then you can perform a Count over the result. This way you'll have directly the result from your database.

The query would look like:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE SITE = 'thesite'
       AND DATE = '<date>'
 GROUP BY SITE, DATE
```

Comment: So what your saying is (for each date in the graph) I select where the date is 20100124 and site is example.org and count the results and return that for each site. Sounds great, I would want to limit the max date range that could be looked up though as doing a query for every day of a given year would be lot of load to put on the sql server.

Comment: Then you can combine the queries :
   SELECT DATE, COUNT(*)  
   FROM YOUR_TABLE
   WHERE SITE = 'thesite'
   GROUP BY SITE

Answer (score 0):

> There must be a better way of doing this,

The web server logs HTML requests.  Most analytical systems use the web server logs.

Since you mentioned that you're doing this to learn, you're gathering statistics in the most flexible way possible.

My only suggestion would be to remove all indexes from the statistics table that your web applications are writing to.  Make a copy of the statistics table for generating the statistics.  The copy would have all of the necessary indexes.

This way, you get the fastest writes, because there are no indexes to update.

If necessary, you can have a primary index or clustering index on the write table.

Comment: My first point of call is to do a google style javascript send data to sever for processing apon page view, I intend to then look into 'internal monitoring' such as processing system logs and tracking apache server-status pages etc as you mention in the first part of your reply. I have to admit that the second part of your response flew right over my head but I am reading up on what you said so I understand it better. Thank you again for responding.